# How to create a variable that incorporates a list and an input

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, char

I'm making a little hangman game for part of a class project and I want it so it will return what the user has already input, the new input and the spaces of the letters the user has yet to guess.  ie. t e _ t

Here's what I've got so far but it puts spaces where they shouldn't be any and sometimes misses letters.

```
word = "test"
word_outline = ""
guess = input()
used_characters = ["t", "e"]

for char in word:
    for used_characters in used_characters:
        if char == used_characters:
            word_outline = word_outline + used_characters
            word_outline = word_outline + " "

    if char != used_characters and char != guess:
            word_outline = word_outline + "_ "


    if char == guess:
        word_outline = word_outline + guess
        word_outline = word_outline + " "

print(word_outline)
```

Comment: I don't see where there would be "spaces that shouldn't be there" with your code... Can you provide us with an example of what the output looks like v the expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You named the variable you are making an iteration with the same way as the list itself with `used characters`. Try to not iterate over your used characters but simply check if the character appears in there.

Here is my take:

```
word = "test"
word_outline = ""
guess = input()
used_characters = ["t", "e"]

for char in word:
   if char in used_characters:
        word_outline += char + ' '
   elif char != guess:
        word_outline += '_ '
   else: # We are sure the character matches from the previous condition
        word_outlines += guess+ ' '
```

I also replaced your `word_outline = word_outline + used_characters` by the operator +=, which does the same thing of adding characters at the end of your file more concisely

Comment: Thanks! This really helped. I'm kinda new to coding so thanks for being clear.

Comment: Happy to help :)
Don't hesitate if you have any question on how the code above works !